# Looping through and processing lines in Bash

Tags: bash

I have the follow file with JSON data (`file.txt`):

```json
{
  "files": [
    "/path/to/index.js",
    "/some/other/path.txt",
    "/another/path/to/file.js"
  ]
}
```

I'd like to do the following:

1. Find each file ending in `.js`. One simple regex might be: `/".*.js"/
2. Loop over each file above and do something with it. E.g maybe call `echo $FILENAME`
3. Replace that line with a relative path. E.g. `"./file.js"`

So the output file might look like:

```json
{
  "files": [
    "./index.js",
    "/some/other/path.txt",
    "./file.js"
  ]
}
```

Bash is the only thing available to use in the environment I am working in. Is it possible to do the above?

I've seen examples of `awk` and other things that look more advanced, but I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: Wait, so is `bash` the only thing available, or is `awk` available, too? What about other tools? `grep`, `perl`, `sed`...?

Comment: No `jq` either?

Comment: `/path/to` and `/another/path/to` can't both resolve to the current directory (unless you postulate that there is a symlink from one to the other, and significantly expand the scope of the question to also inspect the file system and resolve such symlinks).

Comment: `awk`, `grep`, etc.. are available too. I just meant that I can't really use another scripting language like ruby, python, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had access to `jq` you would be able to process it with:

```sh
jq '
.files[] |=
  if . | endswith(".js")
    then . | sub(".*/"; "./")
    else .
  end' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a json parser like `jq` for this but if that's not an option, here is an attempt with `bash` and `basename`:

```
pattern='.js"$'
pattern2='.js",$'

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]] || [[ $line =~ $pattern2 ]]
    then
      printf '"./%s\n' "$(basename "$line")"
    else
      printf "%s\n" "$line"
  fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

How about the following ideas (I allow myself to use common command line tools like `sed` and `jq`).

Option 1 (using `for`)

```
for a in $(jq -r '.files[]' file.txt); do
  if [[ $a =~ \.js$ ]]; then
    echo "$a"
    echo $a | sed 's,.*/\(.*\.js\),\1,g'
  fi
done
```

Option 2 (using `while`)

```
files=$(jq -r '.files[]' file.txt)

while IFS= read -r a; do
  if [[ $a =~ \.js$ ]]; then
    echo "$a"
    echo $a | sed 's,.*/\(.*\.js\),\1,g'
  fi
done <<< $files
```

Two simple examples to build a wider solution on.

Comment: Careful you don't match a file named "something.json" or "ajs.txt". This will break if any of the filenames contains a space: [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Thx @glennjackman. I improved the match expression. I also added an example with `while`.

Comment: `$array` does not produce the elements of the array, and passing it to `while read` is rather uniciomatic if you already have an array. Just loop over it with `for a in "${array[@]}"; do`...